# Add new string value to existing value for text area(long) field with new line using LDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, line-break

I am using `LDS` to load the Account record. i want to add new comments with new line to existing comments for my `textarea(long) field` in Account record. i used `\n` and `\r\n' none of them are working for me . new comment added end of existing comments. is there working work around.
**cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="SeTesting" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
        access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="addingcomments" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="accfields" type="List" default="['Name','Comments__c']"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="Accrecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"                      
                  fields="{!v.accfields}"
                  targetFields="{!v.record}"
                  mode="EDIT"
                  targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdataction}"
                  />
<lightning:textarea aura:id="verifyhswNoselection" 
                                        required="true"
                                        label="Comments"
                                        value="{!v.addingcomments}"
                                        class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
</lightning:textarea>
<lightning:button variant="brand" onclick="{!c.addnewcomment}"/>
```

**controller:**

```
({
  addnewcomment : function (component,event,helper){
    var accrecord = component.get("v.record");
    var newcoments = component.get("v.addingcomments"),
        existingdesc = accrecord.Comments__c,
        todaydt = new Date(),
        existingdesc = (!$A.util.isEmpty(existingdesc)) ? existingdesc + '\n' + newcoments+'--' +todaydt.toLocaleString()+';' : newcoments+'--' +todaydt.toLocaleString()+';';
    accrecord.Comments__c = existingdesc;
    console.log(existingdesc);
    component.set("v.record",accrecord);
      component.find("Accrecord").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
             // record is saved successfully
             self.showStatusToast(component,succmessage,"success");
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            
        }else if(saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE"){
             self.showStatusToast(component,'error occured',"error");
        }else if(saveResult.state === "ERROR"){
            self.showStatusToast(component,'error occured',"error");
            
        }
    }));
},
```

})

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@sdandamud1 I have tried using the code in the initial question. The text area field is being updated perfectly along with the line breaks. I have added images of output in two scenarios

1. When there is text in the field(initial comment) and we add comment from the component

[image: When there is text in the field and we add comment from the component]

2.When there is no text in the field and we add comment from the component.

[image: When there is no text in the field and we add comment from the component]

Can you verify if the Comments__c field is on the layout because the field either has to be on the layout or you have to declare a list of fields in an attribute on the component for LDS to fetch the data.

Comment: i added comment__c field in ` fields="{!v.filedsList}"` even though it's not works for me, what is your field type in salesforce?

Comment: Its a text area long field. can you share the component code after adding the fieldsList attribute?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Can you add the image of the output for "console.log(existingdesc);" in your controller? How does that look? does it have the line break?

Comment: console.log(existingdesc) gives with separate lines but after render UI it shows all comments in one line. updated image with console.log(existingdesc);

Comment: How are you displaying the Field? Is it standard account record page or is it a custom Component?

Comment: standard record page