# Lightning:Textarea value to have new line in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

```
<lightning:textarea value="line 1 \r \n line 2" label="" maxlength="300" /></td></tr>
```

How can I change the value to have different lines so that 'line 1' has its own line and 'line 2' is on its own line. Currently it looks like

[image]

Comment: i also struggling with same issue .https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285403/add-new-string-value-to-existing-value-for-text-arealong-field-with-new-line-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put in multiple lines like this:I have used enter key in between line 1,2 and 3

```
<lightning:textarea value="line 1
                           line 2
                           line 3" label="" maxlength="300" />
```

for setting through javascript just add `"\n"`

```
var valz = "123"+"\n"+"456";
        component.set("v.textareaval",valz);
```

bind this attribute to textarea component

Comment: Oh I didn't expect that to work! Neat! What if the value is stored in an attribute though? How can I save the attribute value with the enter value if it's saved through the apex controller.

Comment: @PeterLuo, added code for attribute setting through javascript

Comment: Thank you, I think my problem was I was trying to put the "\n" directly into the value parameter but I saved the value in my controller and it worked.